# Enumerate all windows in Windows 8

Tags: windows, user32

I'm looking for a simple code to enumerate all windows on Windows 8, in order to look for a Desktop window with a specific title (example: "Untilted - Notepad").

I used:

```
BOOL WINAPI EnumWindows(
  _In_  WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc,
  _In_  LPARAM lParam
);
```

But according to [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `For Windows 8 and later, EnumWindows enumerates only top-level windows of desktop apps.`.

Any alternative for Windows 8 ?

(PS: This follows up [my java question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019805/listing-windows-titles-in-jna-on-windows-8), but I feel .net people can help me more on this).

Comment: Your specification to look *"for a window with a specific title"* is not very detailed. What type of window? Desktop application or Modern UI application? Is this a top-level window or do you want to include child windows as well? Also, this is not really a .NET question - it's a Windows API question. *".NET people"* hardly ever use the Windows API.

Comment: EnumWindows only ever enumerated top-level desktop windows.  The Win8 note is only there to remind you that it won't enumerate Store app windows.  Mostly because they are not real windows.  Not exactly a problem if this is really a Java question.

Comment: Say you opened a test.txt file with notepad. You'll have a window called "Notepad - test.txt".

Comment: Sorry for calling you .Net people :p